# Error including files in php using require_once

Tags: php, require-once

This is my app. root:

```
htdocs

    core/

        init.php

    classes/

        DB.php
        POST.php

    ajax/

        post_feeds.php
```

This is my post_feeds.php;

```
require_once '../core/init.php';
```

The file init.php is there but I don't understand why I am getting this error.

```
Warning: require_once(classes/DB.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache24\htdocs\core\init.php on line 9

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'classes/DB.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Apache24\htdocs\core\init.php on line 9
```

It gives me no error in my `init.php` file when I  `require_once 'classes/DB.php';`

This is `init.php`

```
session_start();

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+2');
//date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Tirane');

//autoload for classes.
require_once 'classes/DB.php';
require_once 'classes/USER.php';
require_once 'classes/NOTIFICATION.php';

if (isset($_COOKIE["user_id"])) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `init.php`? If you have `require_once('classes/DB.php')` in `init.php`, then it's searching for `core/classes/DB.php`.

Comment: No because it loads like this: htdocs/classes/DB.php
This works in my whole app. except htdocs/ajax/post_feeds.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use an absolute path for including files:

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
require_once("{$root}/core/init.php");
```

Or with dirname:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) .'/../core/init.php');
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I used this:
_require_once (__DIR__ .'/../classes/DB.php');_

Answer (score 1):

You dont have problem with including init.php, you have problem with init.php on line 9:

> Warning: require_once(classes/DB.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache24\htdocs\core\init.php ***on line 9***

Open init.php and change your path on line 9 from `require_once('classes/DB.php')` to `require_once('../classes/DB.php')`.

`DB.php` is in `classes` folder in your root, and in line 9 on init.php you are including `ROOT/core/classes/DB.php`.